# Import information from self signed cert into keystore and truststore files

Tags: java, openssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I would like to create a new self signed certificate and move the information into keystore and truststore files. Here are my step.

**1. steps for self signing cert**

--generate the key--

```
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out myRsaKey.key 2048
```

**2. generate the key**

```
openssl req -new -x509 –sha256 -key myRsaKey.key -out myRsaCert.crt -days 365
```

**3. running the job**

```
JAVA=$JAVA_HOME/bin/java
$JAVA \
  -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=$APP_HOME/certificate/project.keystore \
  -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=changeit \
  -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=$APP_HOME/certificate/project.truststore \
  -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit \
  -Djavax.net.debug=ssl \
  -Xmx512m -cp $APP_HOME:$APP_HOME/build:$APP_HOME/certificate:$APP_LIBS com.test.App $1 testString
```

What is the process of transferring the information from step1 and step2(myRsaKey.key and myRsaCert.crt files) to 
  project.keystore and project.truststore files which are passed as argument to the java job run in step 3?

Comment: Do it manually with something like key store explorer.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to create a key and cert. Where I would like to get is take the information from them and move to a keystore and truststore files. I will take a look at Key Store Explorer.

Comment: I find it easy to use anyway for importing/exporting carts anyway.